# There are replacement to "instanceof " in java 8?

Tags: java, oop, java-8, java-stream

How can change the below code to use stream in java 8 to check type object and convert it ? there are other alternative in java 8 ?

```
private void fillObject(Object role, String issuingRange) {

        if (role != null) {
            List<String> rangeList2 = null;
            if (role instanceof ArrayList<?>) {
                rangeList2 = (ArrayList<String>) role ;
            } else if (role instanceof String) {
                rangeList2 = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(role ));
            }
}
```

Comment: Why use an alternative ?

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do that?  This isn't really what streams are for.

Comment: i'am trying to make code better and good performance , you think this approach good ?

Comment: It is very unclear what you actually want. `issuingRange` is unused, `roleList` is undefined. Please provide an example how this is called as well.

Comment: I'm not sure that there's anything wrong with what you've written.  Erwin's solution is certainly an improvement.  But don't try to use streams.  Streams won't help you in any way.  This isn't what they do.

Answer (score 5):

Alternatives for this particular usage of "instanceof" are to just simply have two methods.

```
private void fillObject(ArrayList<String> role, String issuingRange) {
        ...
}
private void fillObject(String role, String issuingRange) {
        fillObject(new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(role)), issuingRange);
}
```

Comment: To properly format code, select it and press the `{}` button in the editor.

Comment: Don’t use raw types, you only need to type two more characters for `new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(role))` though `new ArrayList<>(Collections.singletonList(role))` is more efficient…

Comment: Yeah, and don't use ellipsis either :-)  And don't restrict the List method to ArrayList but allow any form of List.  Come on man.  The question was about instanceof and my answer focused exclusively on that.

Comment: still how will you decide whether to call fillObject(ArrayList<String> role, String issuingRange) or fillObject(String role, String issuingRange)? there could be other type of objects coming in too...

Comment: Yes, in the example any kind of object can come in.  And nothing happens.  If that is the intent and stated as such in the requirements then add a third method fillObject(Object role, String ...).  However, my bet is on this being a beginner's serious design error rather than intended behaviour.